# Use each() after serializeArray() a form

Tags: jquery, serializearray

So I have a form like this:

```
<form>
  <input name="name" value="A. Hitchcock">
  <input name="email" value="a.hitchcock@psychose.com">
  <input name="name" value="Q. Tarantino">
  <input name="email" value="q.tarantino@killbill.com">
  ...
</form>
```

Very simple one. It allow me to get `name` and `email` from my customers. With jQuery I have a button to allowing me to add more customers (`name` and `email`) to my form.

I need to echo these datas on each form changes, so I used this code:

```
$('.form-horizontal').on('change','input', function(){
  var dataArray = $('#list-items').serializeArray();
});
```

With `serializeArray()` I can serialize all my datas into an array.

My problem is to show these datas like this using this `serializeArray()`:

- `A. Hitchcock` has this email address : `a.hitchcock@psychose.com`.
- `Q. Tarantino` has this email address : `q.tarantino@killbill.com`.

Any help on how to do this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest you wrap the pairs in a parent and ignore using serializeArray()

```
<form>
    <div class="person">
        <input name="name[]" value="A. Hitchcock">
        <input name="email[]" value="a.hitchcock@psychose.com">
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <input name="name[]" value="Q. Tarantino">
        <input name="email[]" value="q.tarantino@killbill.com">
    </div>
</form>
```

Then map the values from the groups:

```
var res = $('.person').map(function () {
    var $inputs = $(this).find('input');
    return '<li>' + $inputs.eq(0).val() + ' has this email address :' + $inputs.eq(1).val() + '</li>'
}).get();

$('#list').append(res.join(''));
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cpgmzsyt/)**</kbd>

The objects created by serializeArray() would look like:

```
[{
    "name": "name[]",
    "value": "A. Hitchcock"
}, {
    "name": "email[]",
    "value": "a.hitchcock@psychose.com"
}, {
    "name": "name[]",
    "value": "Q. Tarantino"
}, {
    "name": "email[]",
    "value": "q.tarantino@killbill.com"
}]
```

So parsing those would still require pairing indices to get the name and email anyaway

If you really wanted to do it you could use a `for` loop:

```
var res= [];
for( var i=0; i< arr.length; i=i+2){
     res.push('<li>' + arr[i].value + ' has this email address :' + arr[i+1].value + '</li>');
}
```

Comment: Looks really perfect. One question for you: what about a select instead a input as a second item ?

Comment: if it is a select ...there is a pseudo selector `:input` that looks for all form controls...easy change  http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Without changing anything in your HTML code, you can separate `names` and `emails` in two `Arrays` like following code, and just concatenate them like you want in simple `for` loop:

**Full Js :**

```
$('.form-horizontal').on('change','input', function(){  
    var names = $("form input[name='name']").serializeArray();
    var emails = $("form input[name='email']").serializeArray();

    for(var i=0;i<=names.length;i++){
        alert(names[i].value+" has this email address : "+emails[i].value);
    }
});
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: good thinking...appears you realized what I was trying to point out before